# PHP/MYSQL: formatting user input data as MYSQL timestamp to search mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I'm trying to create a page where a user can search the MySQL general_log between two date and times for all mySQL queries, but I don't know how to go about formatting the user input data so it can be read by the table.

Here's my (very) rough stab at it, I'm kind of lost;
MYSQL query;

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM general_log WHERE event_time between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$fromDate') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$toDate'");
```

Form;

```
            <h1>Query Error Log</h1>    
        <h2>Insert Date/Time as format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS</h2>
        <h2>From Date:Time</h2><input type="number" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" value="" /> <p></p>
        <h2>To Date:Time</h2><input type="number" id="toDate" name="toDate" value="" /> <p></p>
        <p></p><input type="submit">
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM general_log WHERE (event_time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$fromDate') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$toDate'))";
```

Comment: No luck with that sorry,